# Check if there exist A and B such that S=A+B and T=B+A

Tags: algorithms, strings

Two strings $S$ and $T$ are said to be *conjugate* if there are two non-empty strings $A$ and $B$ such that $S = A+B$ and $T = B+A$ ($+$ is concatenation). How can I find if two strings are conjugate or not?

Example: if `S="tokyo"` and `T="kyoto"`, then the pair $(S,T)$ is conjugate, because we can find `A="to"` and `B="kyo"`.

Comment: What's wrong with simply checking all the possible values of A and B?

Comment: The right terminology is *conjugate*.

Answer (score 2):

If $S = A + B$, then $A$ is a [prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_%28computer_science%29#Prefix) of $S$ and $B$ is a [suffix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_%28computer_science%29#Suffix) of $S$. So you only need to try the strings $A$ which are a prefix of $S$ and the strings $B$ which are a suffix of $S$.

Furthermore, given a string $A$, not all suffixes of $S$ can work: only the one $B$ such that $A + B = S$.

So go through the prefixes of $A$, and test them against $T$.

Note: there are more sophisticated algorithms that can run faster. But at this level, what you're expected to write is an algorithm that makes a single pass over all the prefixes of $S$, and for each prefix, determines whether it is part of a solution in time $O(n)$ where $n$ is the length of the strings $S$ and $T$.

Comment: If local search is any help to him, a heuristic that may speed up the process is to only check indices of $S$ such that $S_{i}$ is the last letter of $T$ and $S_{i+1}$ is the first letter of $T$. Maybe use bigrams instead of letters, depending on how "varied" a string $S$ is and how long the words are.